# how to change the look of an image according to the season we like

Tags: python

We are working with Image magik and using python programming language.
We have been able to make some changes to the colours but it does not work for every image and at other times the entire image changes colour not just the required portions .
We only want to change the colours and don't want to add any effects
These are the 2 codes we have used.
first:

```
import Image
import ImageEnhance
img = Image.open( 'image.jpg')
img = img.convert('RGBA')
r, g, b, alpha = img.split()
selection = r.point(lambda i: i > 100 and 300)
selection.save( "autmask.png")
r.paste(g, None, selection)
img = Image.merge( "RGBA", (r, b, g, alpha))
img.save( "newclr.png")
img.show()
```

**and the second.**

```
import Image

# split the image into individual bands
im = Image.open('image.jpg')
im.convert("RGB")
source = im.split()
R, G, B = 0, 1, 2
# select regions where red is less than 100
mask = source[B].point(lambda i: i < 100 and 300)
# process the green band
out = source[G].point(lambda i: i * 2.5)

# paste the processed band back, but only where red was < 100
source[G].paste(out, None, mask)

# build a new multiband image
im = Image.merge(im.mode, source)
im.save( "newimage.png")
im.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the expressions `lambda i: i > 100 and 300` - It will return 300 if i is greater than 100 otherwise it will return `False`.

For the expression: `lambda i: i < 100 and 300` - It will return 300 if i is lesser than 100 otherwise it will return `False`.

This is what you intended?

From what I understand of your code requirement, you may want to replace the first one with `lambda i: i > 100 and i or 300` and second one with `lambda i: i < 100 and i or 300`

Comment: No... my doubt is ... is this code good enough to make changes based on seasons to a picture. Because we are having trouble changing the colours of selected objects . Too many objects of the same colour tend to change colour even though we don't want it so.